# Why allocator using explicit free list need initial heap size as 48bytes?

Tags: c

I'm considering implement allocator using explicit free list and wonder why many people implemented 48bytes as initial size.

But most of people used 48 NOT 24

```
#define PACK(size, alloc)  ((size) | (alloc))
#define PUT(p, val)  (*(size_t *)(p) = (val))  
#define WSIZE       4     
#define DSIZE       8  
#define CHUNKSIZE  (1<<12)
#define OVERHEAD 24 


static char *heap_listp;  /* pointer to first block */  
static char *mem_brk; /* pointer to last byte of heap plus 1 */

void *mem_sbrk(int incr){
    char *old_brk = mem_brk;

    mem_brk +=incr;
    return (void *)old_brk;
}


int mm_init(void)
{
    if((heap_listp = mem_sbrk(48) == NULL){                                      //Return error if unable to get heap space
        return -1;
    }

    PUT(heap_listp, 0);                                                                  
//Put the Padding at the start of heap
    PUT(heap_listp + WSIZE, PACK(OVERHEAD, 1));                                             
//Put the header block of the prologue
    PUT(heap_listp + DSIZE, 0);                                                             
//Put the previous pointer
    PUT(heap_listp + DSIZE + WSIZE, 0);                                                     
//Put the next pointer
    PUT(heap_listp + OVERHEAD, PACK(OVERHEAD, 1));                                          
//Put the footer block of the prologue
    PUT(heap_listp + WSIZE + OVERHEAD, PACK(0, 1));                                         
//Put the header block of the epilogue


    if(extend_heap(CHUNKSIZE / WSIZE) == NULL){                                             //Return error if unable to extend heap space
        return -1;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I think we enough have 6 words(padding, prologue header block, prologue footer block, previous pointer, next pointer, and epilogue header block)
So I think we need to declare like

```
if((heap_listp = mem_sbrk(24)) == NULL)
```

Please feel free to point out what I missing.

Comment: What is the size of a pointer on your platform? Are you on a 32-bit platform (which tend to have 32-bit pointers)? Or are you on a 64-bit platform (which tend to have 64-bit pointers)?

Comment: Sorry i forgot, 64 bit pointers and 4 bytes for a 1 word

Comment: it's unusual to have pointers double the length of a word. Do you mean 4 bytes for an int? (and hopefully for a size_t given those macros)

Comment: also, you use OVERHEAD in that code, which isn't defined

Comment: I'm sorry i added that macro

Answer (score 0):

```
    PUT(heap_listp, 0); //ofset 0                                                                  
    PUT(heap_listp + WSIZE, PACK(OVERHEAD, 1));    //offset 4 - appears to contain a length (of OVERHEAD bytes)
    PUT(heap_listp + DSIZE, 0);           //offset 8                                                  
    PUT(heap_listp + DSIZE + WSIZE, 0);  //offset 8 + 4 = 12                                                   
    PUT(heap_listp + OVERHEAD, PACK(OVERHEAD, 1)); // offset 24 - another length of OVERHEAD bytes                                   
    PUT(heap_listp + WSIZE + OVERHEAD, PACK(0, 1)); //offset 24 + 4
```

Clearly the sbrk needs to be larger than 24 as you're writing to byte 31

So it looks like the initial set up consists of 2 blocks both OVERHEAD bytes long.

Using 2 * OVERHEAD for the sbrk would have been clearer. So would using a struct for the memory area header.

Comment: Why it remains blank between offset 12 and offset 24? Do we have to? Also does not need to make pointer variable 2 words in 64 bit system?

Comment: I have no idea. I didn't write this allocator